# How to Find the Coefficients For the Chebyshev Expansion of a Function

Tags: approximation-theory, chebyshev-polynomials

Find and building a Fourier series of a function $f(x)$ on an arbitrary interval $[a,b]$ is explained [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_series#Definition). I know that for Chebyshev series, the expansion is $$f(x) \sim \sum_{i=0}^{N} c_i T_i(x)$$ as $N \to \infty$.
However, how would you find each $c_i$, specifically for $f$ on $[a,b]$?

Comment: By [taking the inner product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev_polynomials#Orthogonality) with $T_{j}(x), j \in \mathbb{N}$, and using that the Chebyshev series is orthogonal with respect to a particular weight function. The procedure is the same as what you would do to compute Fourier series coefficients.

Comment: @mattos So, it's $$c_i=\frac2{b-a} \int_{a}^{b} \frac{f(x) \cdot T_i(x)}{\sqrt{1-x^2}} \, dx$$?

Comment: No, its not. See the link above.

Comment: @mattos Did I fix it now? I'm a bit confused.

Comment: No, you have written the inner product for when $x \in [-1,1]$ but you have an arbitrary interval $[a,b]$. You have to rescale your weight function accordingly.

Comment: @mattos How would I do that?